# looping through object literal and array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, for-in-loop

I believe I am having an issue with my looping of object literals and arrays.
I am trying to use an object literal for the 'map' where I had used an array before. The reason I want to use an object literal is because I want a variable to display the name of the position it is in. As of right now I always get an issue with loc[2][1] = player;.

```
var room0 = [
        [blank, blank, blank, blank],
        [blank, blank, blank, blank],
        [blank, player, blank, doorRight],
        [blank, blank, blank, blank]
];
var room1 = [
        [blank, blank, blank, blank],
        [blank, blank, blank, blank],
        [blank, blank, blank, blank],
        [blank, blank, blank, blank]
];

var loc = room0;

var map = {
    "living room": room0,
    "Bedroom": room1,
    "Outside": room2
};

function moveRight() {
    for (var y = 0; y < loc.length; y++) {
        var posX = loc[y].indexOf(player);
        if (posX <= -1) continue;

        // if going to the next room to the right
        if (loc[y][posX+1] == doorRight) {

            for (var name in map) {
                if (loc == map[name]) {
                    var rightLoc = map[name+1];
                }
            }


            loc[y][posX] = blank;
            loc = rightLoc;
            loc[2][1] = player;
            break;
        }

        if (loc[y][posX+1]  != blank) break;
        if (posX < loc[y].length - 1) {
            loc[y][posX] = blank;
            loc[y][posX + 1] = player; 
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: where is room2 defined ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the actual question, but: this is already the kind of complexity where I'd suggest using classes. It would make naming the rooms easier, too.

Comment: @IngoBürk: What would that help here? Then all those variables would be object properties, and… ?

Comment: Perhaps I did a poor job at explaining what is going on.... I'll try editing it to be more clear.

Comment: I didn't think it was necessary to show you where the player is defined or room2. Sorry, I just didn't think you would want to look through a lot of code.... The definition of the player/room2/blank obviously isn't the issue here.

Comment: Got it.  That's just the first step we're all gonna take to debugging that line of code.  Now that I look closer, I think I've found the problem.  See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to hold different things in your map, because `map[name+1]` doesn't magically point to the next room identified by `name`.

```
var map = {
    "living room": 0,
    "Bedroom": 1,
    "Outside": 2
};

var rooms = [room0, room1, room2];
```

Now, `map['living room']` will hold the index in `rooms`, so you can still use numeric addition to "move" into the next room. Your code will then become:

```
var rightLoc;

for (var name in map) {
    if (loc == map[name]) {
        rightLoc = map[name] + 1;
    }
}

loc = rooms[rightLoc];
```

This code still lacks some checks to make sure you always have a room to go into, but I'm sure you can figure that out yourself :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like *rightLoc* will be undefined when that line of code is reached.

The variable *rightLoc* gets set to the value of `map[name + 1]`

Because the properties of *map* are strings, `name + 1` will be a string that ends with `1`.

Therefore, *map[name + 1]* is undefined and cannot be de-referenced.

The key point is that your for loop is iterating over the properties of your object.

For each iteration of the loop, name will be a string.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HjZeq/1/) that demonstrates the problem:

```
var map = {
    "living room": 'room0',
        "Bedroom": 'room1',
        "Outside": 'room2'
};

for (var name in map) {
    if (name === 'Bedroom') {
        var badKey = name + 1;
        var theType = typeof map[badKey];
        alert('key: ' + badKey + ' type: ' + theType);
    }
}
```

output:

```
key: Bedroom1 type: undefined
```

---

If you read the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), you'll see that the *for in loop* iterates over object properties in **arbitrary order**, which means this technique will not work.

---

Two important tools that can help you find errors like this quicker:

- read the documentation (google "*javascript mdn for in loop*")
- learn to use a debugger (inspecting variables is **SUPER** easy with Firebug)